# How to create a text file with python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, text-files

how would i go about making a code that makes a text file from the output of the program. For example: a code that "rolls a dice" and outputs a random number. How would i make that random number be made into a .txt file? I am on mac.

Comment: If you really want to "make a text file from the output of the program", you can do that with shell redirection, or `sys.stdout` redirection from within Python. But it's often much more sensible to just `open` a file and `write` lines to it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a replacement for a google search. Please do not ask questions here you have not attempted to search an answer for on your own.

Comment: I have used google. I have been searching for an hour and nothing worked

Comment: You don't have to write the stdout of your program to a file, a much better way to do this would be to open a file and write the str representation of your random number to this.  This is googleable, but I, unlike some, understand that you may have been thinking about this the wrong way and your googling came up with nothing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Are you simply asking how to write text to a file?

Comment: how to write the output to a text file

Comment: So `with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile: outfile.write(str(random.randint(1, 6)))` solves your problem?

Comment: yes, that sovled it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this in the same directory as your script in command prompt.

`python your_script.py > output.txt`

If you want to do this within the script itself:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f: 
    f.write("Random Number")
```